I dream of using a hash function to scramble or otherwise 'ruin' a JPEG image, is this possible?
I know that compression functions are used to make JPEGs smaller, but what if I used a hash function? I imagine it would be able to make it even smaller, but because it's irreversible, it would just 'ruin' the image. I would like to see this in action. Is it possible? If so, how? I'm imagining I could just change the JPEG into a text file and then change it from there somehow, but I have no idea.

Maybe read a little bit on https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/JPEG first?
